# How do I extend sun.awt.windows to extract a non-standard clipboard format so that I can support drag and drop from a native application?

Tags: java, reflection, drag-and-drop, awt, clipboard

I am trying to support drag and drop from a native Windows application into a Java application. My problem has been that I have no documentation, and so I have been reverse-engineering it. My first issue was that I didn't know the name of the clipboard format. Working in the debugger, I was able to find the identifier of the custom clipboard format that the application had registered using the system call `RegisterClipboardFormat()`. And in `sun.awt.windows.WDataTransferer`, there's a native interface to the system call `GetClipboardFormatName()`, by which I managed to extract the registered name. (For reference, though it doesn't bear directly on the problem, the application is Eudora 7.1 and the name is `EudoraTransferClipboardFormat`.)

Now I anticipate needing to do this again, and I'd rather write a small utility now because I'm certain to forget the internal data structures of the library by the time I need it later. The problem is that the relevant clipboard format identifier is buried inside a subclass instance of `SunDropTargetContextPeer` as private member `currentT`. Navigation from the drag-and-drop event to this object likewise goes through a protected member. And the system call interface is likewise declared private. This is all visible in the debugger, but not in ordinary code.

My goal is to extract the value of `currentT` (since that's what the drag and drop subsystem actually sees) and display the name of the registered clipboard formats therein. I suspect various abuses of the class loader and security system are necessary to get this working as a publishable utility written in Java.

Comment: What native application?  What data is being D'n'D?

Comment: As I mentioned, the application is Eudora 7.1. What's being dragged is an email message. Internally, it's used to arrange messages in folders, but this particular drag type is exposed to the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using Java reflection calls to obtain the relevant internal members. The key part of this is the function `setAccessible` on the `Field` objects. This function turns off access control on the Field object, allowing public access, albeit not through the ordinary syntax. (Note the actual function name; it's not `subvertAccessControls`.) This call succeeds in the ordinary JRE environment and probably won't work in, say, an applet. I didn't bother checking this because this is for a developer tool to examine a drag event for native types that won't otherwise show up because (1) the application doesn't know about the native type and (2) there's no data flavor to translate the native data transfer into a Java object. Therefore, I only need it running once per application that has a drag type I'm reverse engineering; running in the ordinary JRE is all I need.

Thank goodness I didn't have to break out `java.lang.instrument` or even JVMTI. I did, however, have to abuse the security system.

Tested code fragment below. The variable `long native_types[]` is the output. `DropTargetDragEvent dtde` is the input; it's an argument to an event handler.

```
long native_types[];
try {
    /*
     * Retrieve the drop target context.
     *
     * We can retrieve this member directly, because it's a public field.
     */
    DropTargetContext dtc = ( ( DropTarget ) dtde.getSource() ).getDropTargetContext();
    /*
     * Retrieve the drop target context peer.
     *
     * We cannot retrieve this member without reflection, because it's a private field. We get the class
     * object from the public class declaration. The field "dropTargetContextPeer" is private, so we
     * have to retrieve with a reflection call and then set it to be accessible so that we don't get
     * IllegalAccessException when we call get() on the field. Since we're only going to use reflection
     * on the drop target context peer, we don't bother trying to cast it and just leave it declared
     * as Object.
     */
    Class<DropTargetContext> DTC_class = DropTargetContext.class;
    Field DTCP_field = DTC_class.getDeclaredField( "dropTargetContextPeer" );
    DTCP_field.setAccessible( true );
    Object dtcp = DTCP_field.get( dtc );
    /*
     * Retrieve the array of native types.
     *
     * This is almost exactly analogous to the previous retrieval, but with the exception that the field
     * is defined in the superclass, not the class itself. Because the field is declared private, we can't
     * simply use getField(), since that only works on public fields. So we get the class object for the
     * parent class and proceed as before.
     *
     * As a bonus, this routine is cross-platform. The class sun.awt.windows.WDropTargetContextPeer is
     * the implementation class for sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer for Windows. The type identifiers,
     * though, all fit into a long for every platform.
     */
    Class<?> DTCP_class = dtcp.getClass();
    Class<?> DTCP_superclass = DTCP_class.getSuperclass();
    Field CT_field = DTCP_superclass.getDeclaredField( "currentT" );
    CT_field.setAccessible( true );
    native_types = ( long[] ) CT_field.get( dtcp );
} catch ( Exception e ) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Did not retrieve native types.", e );
}
```